# how to tag UIImage in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to toggle UITableViewCell image - cell.imageView.image. (eg. Red <--> Green)

If the current image is green, the image suppose to change to Red when the user click the UITableViewCell.

Once I set the image

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"];
```

How to detect which image is the cell currently using?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit crude, but you should be able to set up an if statement like the following:

```
if ([cell.imageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"]]) {
    // image is green;
} else {
    // image is red;
}
```

I tested it out just to make sure and it works fine

Comment: This is a *lot* more expensive than simply comparing `int`s like I am doing.

Answer (score 2):

Set the [`tag`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW25) on the `imageView` itself:

```
#define IMAGE_TAG_GREEN 50
#define IMAGE_TAG_RED   51

-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
  static NSString *CELL_ID = @"some_cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_ID];
  if(cell == nil) {
     //do setup here...
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CELL_ID] autorelease];
     cell.imageView.tag = //some logic here...
  }
  if(cell.imageView.tag == IMAGE_TAG_GREEN) {
    //...
  } else {
    //...
  }
  return cell;
}
```

**Since `tag` is an inherited property from `UIView`, you cannot use it with `UIImage` itself, but you *can* use it with `UIImageView`**

Answer (score 1):

I believe just add a **Boolean expression** and make it TRUE if it is green and FALSE if it is red. 
Make this boolean expression **extern type** so that this could be a global expression. 
Set the boolean value on clicking the image.
I believe this would be of some help.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to this - but I imagine you could use an if/then statement.

```
If (cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"]) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"];
} else
{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"];
}
```

Or you could go really fancy and use the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Vala.2C_Objective-C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript.2C_ActionScript). Something like the following (note the code below is probably wrong - but should hopefully get you started!):

```
cell.imageView.image = ([UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"]) ? 
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"]; : 
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"];
```

Let us know how you go with this.

Kolya

Comment: as said before, do NOT compare images, is expensive ed definitively stupid even on desktop.
tagging is the preferred way, as Apple use for example here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html